# Website build with asp, link are boken

Tags: asp-classic

I have inherited work from a previous employee. The issue I'm having is a bunch of links are broken,  here the site http://www.essexdrugaction.org. If you visit the site and click on the slider, then click "about us" menu link this message show up

`http://www.essexdrugaction.org/Aboutus2.asp?Category=About%20Us&SubCategory=EDAP`

I dont know `"asp"`

Can anyone help me fix it

Comment: I don't see any slider nor a link to about us.  That about us url doesn't exist.  This is not a programming problem.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones you can see broken links [here](http://www.essexdrugaction.org/Links.asp?Category=Useful%20Links) in the *About Us* menu items, but you're right it's not programming question. Jermaine - do you have any actual "about us" page on the server? Can you contact that previous employee?

Comment: Nope my boss sacked him a long while ago, and i never meet him lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.essexdrugaction.org/Aboutus2.asp?Category=About%20Us&SubCategory=EDAP

this link passes information with url...

if you have original source code of published copy...please debug it properly...

If u dun knw debugging...tell me

If problem solve ...mark it as answer

Comment: i found out the the orignal source code is missing, to make things worst the site was built using html tables...    how do i debug this

Comment: thats y i told you debug , find the missing data....

Comment: i given up trying to debug something i dont understand, before i break somethink im just going to find a backup.

Comment: from where you redirect you page ...  put watch or breakpoint before loading.... after that out breakpoint over "ABOUTUS.asp" page load event ....

if you don't knw how to debug ...just follw following link

http://niharstechnicalfunda.blogspot.in/2012/03/how-to-debug-code.html